# How to create a new list in mailchimp using Java.?

Tags: java, mailchimp

Actually, I found some documentation for that. But, I need the dependencies for creating a list in Mailchimp. Doucmentation for creating a list, https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/partnerapi/1.3/createlist.func.php

Comment: If, some body know about this. Please, let me know your answers..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V1.3 is deprecated.Also,in 1.3,you have to generate app_key in order to create list(which is a tedious job).Check here:

> https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/partnerapi/

Try 3.0(Live API)

> http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/resources/lists/lists-collection

Let me know if you make any progress in creating list as me too started working on same problem yesterday.

Also,you can try ecwid-mailchimp package.

Comment: Sure. And, ecwid-mailchimp package doesn't have any method's to create a list.

Comment: They are REST API's. Check how to use https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/ from this link.I've done it and i was retrieve list id from the api.